# React native: Bad app performance after loading images

Tags: reactjs, image, performance, react-native, expo

**There seems to be no problem with LOADING the images. But there is a problem after they are already loaded.**

In my app I load card images one by one throughout the game. Once I get to a point that I loaded 40 card images, the whole app becomes slow. It always happens at the 40th image, and when I continue loading more card images after the 40th, it becomes slower after each image load.

Practical details:

1. React native with **expo**
2. Requiring **Images from Local** folder into an array and importing that array.
3. Single Image size between 15KB - 120KB, all images together: **3.1MB**
4. Component used for displaying the image: `Image` (react native simple image component)
5. Using `Array.map` to display all images

**Switching all the images with ugly images with a total of 300KB - makes the app run fast without any problem**

The required array imported:

```
const CardsUris = [
  {uri:require('../assets/AC.png'), key:'AC'},
  {uri:require('../assets/AD.png'), key:'AD'},
  {uri:require('../assets/AH.png'), key:'AH'},
  {uri:require('../assets/AS.png'), key:'AS'}...
]
```

Component tree structure:

```
- Base
    - Container
        - <Image source={CardsUris[index].uri} />
```

Is there a way I can troubleshoot this problem? I couldn't find anything about such a problem that appears after loading the images.

Comment: same issue, even ifaced with just 3 500 KB images, app was crashing in iphone6

Answer (score 2):

I feel your pain.

One thing I found that you can try to boost up the performance is [bundling the image assets into your binary](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/preloading-and-caching-assets/). To do that with Expo, use the `assetBundlePatterns` key in the app.json to provide a list of paths in your project directory:

```
"assetBundlePatterns": [
  "assets/images/*"
],
```

Another approach is to use an alternative package that renders images than the default one. React Native's `Image` component handles image caching like browsers for the most part. Many times for use-cases like yours I've noticed flickering, low performance loading from the cache and low performance in general.

So what you could try is [FastImage](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image) - an `Image` replacement that solves these issues. Below the hood, FastImage is a wrapper around [SDWebImage (iOS)](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) and [Glide (Android)](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), so that's the secret sauce.

Do you render the images in a `<FlatList />`? If so, I'd give [react-native-optimized-flatlist](https://github.com/ch4ostic/react-native-optimized-flatlist) a shot too. This is an optimized version of React Native's `<FlatList />` component that removes every item that is not inside the viewport.

If nothing else helps, I'd go for lower quality thumbnails for the images when they're all 40 in grid view.

Comment: Thank you for a clear and detailed answer. Unfortunately, non of the ideas solved the performance issue, and I am going to use compressed and less pretty images.

Comment: Unfortunately, based on my experience, that's the best you can do. You can also try to compress your images with TinyPNG (or something similar), but I guess you've already done that anyway. Sometimes if the resolutions of the images are too high, lower quality thumbnails is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You can try to use FastImage with preloading.
https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image#fastimagepreload-source--void

Comment: Expo doesn't support FastImage so this does not help in the OP's case.