# React native application crashes when I try to display local images on iOS

Tags: react-native

Im trying to build an application that can display images stored locally on the device itself. This application is only targeted for iPads. I'm using `react-native-fs` library to read the local images and set the path inside an array. All of that is working fine. The problem occurs when I try to display the images. Even if I only have 3-4 images, the app hangs if I navigate to the screen where I display the images in a Flatlist. This issue gets worse as I add more images. Around 70 images, the application starts to crash and its not at all responsive.

If I replace the local image urls with remote url, everything is fine. Images load properly and app does not hang. It seems this only occurs with local images.

I tried using `react-native-fast-image` but it didn't help much. And I also read that fast image is not necessary for local images.

Here is my code:

ImageGallery.js (This component is where the app hangs)

```js
export default ({ navigation, route }) => {

  const [state, setState] = useState(initState);

  const { data, name } = route.params;

  const closeModal = () => setState(initState);
  const openModal = (i) => setState({ visible: true, image: i });

  const onImageChange = (i) => {
    setState(s => {
      return {...s, image: i }
    });
  }

  const onSelect = (_, i) => {
    openModal(i);
  }

  const renderImage = ({ item, index }) => {
    const url = `file://${item.data}`;
  
    return(
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.imageWrap}
        onPress={(e) => onSelect(e, index)}
      >
        <FastImage
          source={{ uri: url }}
          style={styles.thumbnail}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  } 

  return(
    <View style={common.container}>
      <Header navigation={navigation} title={name} />
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        numColumns={3}
        renderItem={renderImage}
        initialNumToRender={12}
      />
      {state.visible && (
        <ImageModal
          visible={state.visible}
          title={name}
          images={data}
          index={state.image}
          onClose={closeModal}
          navigation={navigation}
          onChange={onImageChange}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

The data is already loaded before navigating to this page. This is the structure:

```js
[
  {
    data: "/Users/syl/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AEAA4545-7D49-48B2-8BA3-2D44FECD3579/data/Containers/Data/Application/B21896AD-1E9B-4D7B-AEFC-1BDF8843347F/Documents/Main/Samyukta/photos/Event/YOGS4626 copy.jpg",
    name: "YOGS4626 copy.jpg"
  },
  {
    data: "/Users/syl/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AEAA4545-7D49-48B2-8BA3-2D44FECD3579/data/Containers/Data/Application/B21896AD-1E9B-4D7B-AEFC-1BDF8843347F/Documents/Main/Samyukta/photos/Event/VIVI9362 copy.jpg",
    name: "VIVI9362 copy.jpg"
  },
  {
    data: "/Users/syl/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AEAA4545-7D49-48B2-8BA3-2D44FECD3579/data/Containers/Data/Application/B21896AD-1E9B-4D7B-AEFC-1BDF8843347F/Documents/Main/Samyukta/photos/Event/DJI_0261 copy.jpg",
    name: "DJI 0261 copy.jpg"
  }
]
```

As I mentioned, this only seems to be an issue with local images. I thought local images would be more performant because they don't require caching?

I am stuck at this point. Has anyone else faced this issue? Is there something I can do to optimise disk image rendering? Let me know if any more information is required. Any help is appreciated...

RN version: 0.61.3

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61173487/9745240 .

Comment: The post mentions bundling assets into binary in an expo project. How would I bundle images in the file system?